# How to escape whitepace in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, escaping, whitespace, html-entities

I know that rails automatically escapes characters like '<' or '&', but this does nothing for multiple spaces next to each other. I would like to escape everything, including spaces.

I understand that normally you don't want to use `&nbsp;` and that you should use css instead. However, I'm trying to take user input and display it, so css isn't feasible.

For example, I have the user input:     `test`    . When I display it with `<%=@user_input%>` in the view, the extra whitespace is displayed as a single space (though it appears correctly in the source).

Is there an easy way to escape the whitespace? Should I just use `h @user_input` and then replace all the spaces?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The whitespace isn't removed. Browsers simply interpret multiple whitespace characters as a single space.

You could convert each space to `&nbsp;` if you want:

```
<%= raw @user_input.gsub(/\s/, "&nbsp;") %>
```

You could alternatively replace each space with an empty `<span class="whitespace"></span>` tag, and then use CSS to style the whitespace 'characters' however you like.

Finally, you can do this with [only CSS](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/white-space) too using the `white-space: pre` style *(example below)*.

- http://jsfiddle.net/G3VnY/

**Edit** *(to answer the follow-up in your comment)*

```
<%= raw h("this      is      a    sample   &  with   ampersand.").gsub(/\s/, "&nbsp;") %>
```

This escapes the `&` as `&amp;` in the source *(and will do similar for other HTML entities)*, and then does the `" "` to `&nbsp;` conversion.

Comment: You are right, I misspoke about whitespace being removed. However, I'd still like the @user_input to have the other entities escaped as well... Will raw do this for me? Also, could you please explain why you might want to use the spans instead of `&nbsp;`? Which is correct?

Comment: You can't explicitly style `&nbsp;`. If, for example, you wanted each whitespace to be a couple pixels thinner or wider, or maybe each whitespace to have a slight grey background for some reason, you can't do this by styling `&nbsp;`. That's why there is some benefit to using the span-tag approach. It depends on your needs, really.

Comment: You're not 'escaping' whitespace, why do you want to escape other characters? For example, are you wanting `&` to appear as `&amp;` or `&` when displayed?

Comment: Because if I have the user input `  <p>Hello!</p>  `, I don't want it to display the paragraph, I want it to display the text exactly as the user gave it.

Comment: Check my updated reply; I hope that will answer your question.

Comment: Yep! Thank you so much, I think the only css solution is exactly what I need actually! Not an answer to the question I asked, but an answer to the question I meant, which is the best kind of answer. 

The only other thing is that for your edit, it seems raw isn't required if h is called. At least it worked as expected (the &'s weren't getting escaped) when I tested it without the raw.

Comment: Yeah, the `h` converts `&` to `&amp;`, which is valid HTML. Glad you got it sorted out.

Comment: No. I meant that in your edit you don't need to call raw. Though rails automatically escapes &'s typically, it seems that it will not escape the &'s in the replaced spaces. You can test this yourself by using <%=h("this      is      a    sample   &  with   ampersand.").gsub(/\s/, "&nbsp;") %>.

Comment: You lost me now, but that's alright. Without `raw`, the `&` in `&nbsp;` is escaped, causing it to appear as `&amp;nbsp;` in the source.

Comment: No, that's what I'm trying to tell you. That's what you'd expect, but I just tested it and that's not how it behaves. It does NOT escape the &'s in the &nbsp;s WITHOUT the raw. Raw is not needed.

Comment: Note that running `raw` on user input is a big XSS security breach.